# SQL Oracle hierarchy query to get all parents AND children

Tags: oracle, parent-child, hierarchical-data, connect-by

I am trying to build one SQL query that returns both all parents and all children.

This first SQL returns all parents given a base

```
    SELECT BASE,
         LISTAGG (PARENT_ENTITY_ID, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BASE)
            AS PARENTS
    FROM (    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT CHILD_ENTITY_ID BASE,
                     CHILD_ENTITY_ID,
                     PARENT_ENTITY_ID
                FROM P360_RCT_ENTTY_RLTNSHP
          CONNECT BY PRIOR PARENT_ENTITY_ID = CHILD_ENTITY_ID)
GROUP BY BASE
```

This second SQL returns all children given the base

```
SELECT BASE,
         LISTAGG (CHILD_ENTITY_ID, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY BASE)
            AS CHILDREN
    FROM (    SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT PARENT_ENTITY_ID BASE,
                     CHILD_ENTITY_ID,
                     PARENT_ENTITY_ID
                FROM P360_RCT_ENTTY_RLTNSHP
          CONNECT BY PRIOR CHILD_ENTITY_ID=PARENT_ENTITY_ID)
GROUP BY BASE
```

Is there any way to return both of them in one single SQL query where I pass the base and I get a list of children and parents? I searched on SO and found several questions related to the topic but not specifically on getting both parents and children in one query.

Comment: What is the desired output from the single SQL query?

Comment: Let's say I have base = A which has children 1,2,3 and parents 4,5,6. Then I want in one row: A, children=1;2;3 and parents 4;5;6.

Comment: Why don't you wish to join these two queries on `parents.base = children.base`?